# How to access nested dict using @property

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, python-decorators

I am able to set class attributes by using @property decorator using the following code, however I am not able to set attributes(in a hierarchy) in case it is a nested dict.
For example if we need to print the value of 'port' which is within nested 'credentials' dict then how can I use print(obj.credentials.port) rather than using print(obj.port)

```
class TestDec:
    def __init__(self,value) -> None:
        self.value = value
    @property
    def description(self):
        return self.value["description"]
    @property
    def credentials(self):
        return self.value["credentials"]
    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.value["credentials"]["username"]  
    @property
    def password(self):
        return self.value["credentials"]["password"]   
    @property
    def port(self):
        try:
            return self.value["credentials"]["port"]      
        except KeyError:
            pass                    

obj = TestDec({"description":"test decorator","credentials":{"username":"abc","password":"xxxx","port":"5432"}})
print(obj.description)
print(obj.credentials)
print(obj.username)
print(obj.password)
print(obj.port)
```

Comment: Just access `obj.value["credentials"]` like the `@property` function does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have an error with `obj.username` and similar and it should be `obj.credentials.username` (like in my example below), or you want to recursively search for key, which I don't think is a good idea. But for this nested dot accessing elements of dictionary, this could be sufficient.

```py
from collections import UserDict


class MyDict(UserDict):
    def __getattr__(self, arg):
        try:
            result = self.data[arg]
        except KeyError as error:
            raise AttributeError from error

        if isinstance(result, dict):
            return MyDict(result)
        return result


obj = MyDict(
    {
        "description": "test decorator",
        "credentials": {"username": "abc", "password": "xxxx", "port": "5432"},
    }
)
print(obj.description)
print(obj.credentials)
print(obj.credentials.username)
print(obj.credentials.password)
print(obj.credentials.port)
```

Comment: If you'd need to set value with same dot notation, consider taking a look at `__setattr__()`